# Laravel Response::json returns mysql_native_password got packets out of order

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel-4, swift

I am building an application in swift, with the backend in Laravel (so we can port to android as well). The laravel app is connected to the database just fine (it worked a week ago) then we changed the api url to online servers which I now need to change back to my localhost to test more of the backend development.

But now when getting the data back from the server, it says:

```
J���
5.5.38�Ù���3FEgW_Vp�ˇ˜�Ä����������T4E?L@:AwU&X�mysql_native_password�!��ˇÑ#08S01Got packets out of order
```

Here is the code for the createUser function in laravel:

```
public function createUser() {

    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), array(
        'username' => 'required|min:1|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|min:1',
        'email' => 'required|unique:users|email'
    ));

    if($validator->fails()) {
//            return $validator->messages()->toJson();
        return Response::json(array('success' => false, 'error_message' => 'That email or password is already in use'));
    } else {
        $user = User::create(array(
            'username' => Input::get('username'),
            'password' => password_hash(Input::get('password'), PASSWORD_BCRYPT),
            'email' => Input::get('email'),
            'type' => 'business',
            'active' => 1
        ));

        if($user) {
            $user2 = DB::table('users')->where('email', Input::get('email'))->first();
            return Response::json(array('success' => true , 'userid' => $user2->userid));
        } else {
            return Response::json(array('success' => false, 'error_message' => 'The user could not be created'));
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the code in swift (It works with an online server responding in JSON as well):

```
if ( username.isEqualToString("") || password.isEqualToString("") || email.isEqualToString("")) {

        var alertView:UIAlertView = UIAlertView()
        alertView.title = "Sign Up Failed!"
        alertView.message = "Please enter Email, Username and Password"
        alertView.delegate = self
        alertView.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
        alertView.show()
    } else {

        var post:NSString = "username=\(username)&password=\(password)&email=\(email)"

        NSLog("PostData: %@",post);

        var url:NSURL = NSURL.URLWithString("http://localhost:3306/laravel/project/createUser/")

        var postData:NSData = post.dataUsingEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding)

        var postLength:NSString = String( postData.length )

        var request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        request.HTTPBody = postData
        request.setValue(postLength, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
        request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")


        var error: NSError?
        var response: NSURLResponse?

        var urlData:NSData = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse:&response, error:&error)

        let res = response as NSHTTPURLResponse!;

        NSLog("Response code: %ld", res.statusCode);

        if (res.statusCode >= 200 && res.statusCode < 300)
        {
            var responseData:NSString  = NSString(data:urlData, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)

            NSLog("Response ==> %@", responseData);

            var error: NSError?

            let jsonData:NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlData, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers , error: &error) as NSDictionary


            let success = jsonData.valueForKey("success").integerValue

            //[jsonData[@"success"] integerValue];

            NSLog("Success: %ld", success);

            if(success == 1)
            {
                NSLog("Register SUCCESS");
                self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
            } else {
                var error_msg:NSString

                if jsonData["error_message"] as? NSString {
                    error_msg = jsonData["error_message"] as NSString
                } else {
                    error_msg = "Unknown Error"
                }
                var alertView:UIAlertView = UIAlertView()
                alertView.title = "Register Failed!"
                alertView.message = error_msg
                alertView.delegate = self
                alertView.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
                alertView.show()

            }

        } else {
            var alertView:UIAlertView = UIAlertView()
            alertView.title = "Register Failed!"
            alertView.message = "Connection Failed"
            alertView.delegate = self
            alertView.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
            alertView.show()
        }
    }
```

The database is help in MySQL Workbench on `localhost:3306`. In the Swift code, I have also tried `myname.local/` and `localhost`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Laravel + Swift = nice! I've been waiting for that for so long... :)

Comment: It looks like it is an error inside Laravel and it has nothing to do with your Swift client code.

Comment: Could you take a look at the PHP logs (located in `app/storage/logs`)? If there is something related to your error, please include it in the question.